# Futhark in an R package via Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, futhark

I would like to call functions written in the small functional programming language [Futhark](https://futhark-lang.org/) in R via Rcpp. That works, because the Futhark compiler can generate C code and C libraries can be accessed in R via Rcpp.

I managed to come up with a working prototype here: https://github.com/nevrome/R.futhark.example

Now I wonder if I can simplify the development cycle and reduce the amount of boilerplate/wrapper code I have to manually write for individual functions.

Here's my general workflow (Futhark -> C -> C++ -> R) with an example:

**futhark_test.fut**: The manually written Futhark code file. It gets compiled to C (**futhark_test.h** and **futhark_test.c**) with the Futhark compiler (`futhark c --library ...`)

```
let main (x: i32) (y: i32): i32 =
  x * 2 + y * 3
```

**futhark_bridge_c_cpp.c**: C code to wrap the C function in **futhark_test.c** generated by the Futhark compiler

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include "futhark_test.h"

int32_t futhark_entry_main_c(int32_t a, int32_t b) {
  struct futhark_context_config *cfg = futhark_context_config_new();
  struct futhark_context *ctx = futhark_context_new(cfg);
  int32_t res;
  futhark_entry_main(ctx, &res, a, b);
  return res;
}
```

**futhark_bridge_rcpp.cpp**: C++ code to wrap the C function and manage the interaction with R

```
#include "Rcpp.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

extern "C" int32_t futhark_entry_main_c(int32_t a, int32_t b);

//' Call C function
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP futhark_entry_main_cpp(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
  int32_t a_mod = Rcpp::as<int32_t>(a);
  int32_t b_mod = Rcpp::as<int32_t>(b);
  int32_t ab = futhark_entry_main_c(a_mod, b_mod);
  return Rcpp::wrap(ab);
}
```

Rcpp automatically (`Rcpp::compileAttributes()`) creates **RcppExports.cpp** and **RcppExports.R** from **futhark_bridge_rcpp.cpp** and I can call the function originally written in Futhark via `futhark_entry_main_cpp(1, 2)` in R.

To automate my development process I created an R script **build.R** with the following sequence of commands

```
devtools::document()
Rcpp::compileAttributes()
system("cd src && futhark c --library futhark_test.fut")
devtools::install()
```

That allows me to modify the Futhark code, run these commands and then test the outcome in R. Of course only if I do not change the Futhark function's interface. If I do so I have to edit both the C as well as the C++ wrapper code.

Is there a way to reduce the complexity of this process and does my solution have any obvious shortcomings?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question. I also think it's a reasonable question to ask "why are you doing this?". It seems unlikely that the efficiency talked about on the futhark home page will survive a trip through a C transpiler and a c++ compiler. I'm willing to bet that the C++ compiler is smarter than the futhark -> C transpiler at optimising code. What you are doing is fairly complex, and I think your workflow just matches that. I don't think there is a straightforward way of allowing your futhark function's interface to change without modifying your C++ code. Looks fine to me.

Comment: Alright - thank you very much for this assessment! It's good to know that I haven't overlooked any obvious things and can continue to experiment! I'm doing this mostly to get a bit more familiar with functional programming and the integration with R helps me to make use of Futhark in other side projects. Of course I hoped I could access its parallelization features, but I understand your argument that I will most likely lose efficiency. That's ok - speed was not my main concern.

Comment: R also has an [interface to OpenCL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenCL/index.html), so you could also use the Futhark -> OpenCL compiler.

Comment: Cool! That may make this endeavor actually useful performance-wise, or?